# Нарушается кодировка в блоке div

Tags: html, ajax, кодировка

Делал всё, как на примере, почему-то у нарушается кодировка именно в этом блоке DIV
Есть добрые люди, которые могут помочь в решении данной проблемы? Вот собственно пример: [AJAX подгрузка контента в указанный DIV](http://feo-klunker.blogspot.com/2009/09/ajax-div.html).

Answer (score 1):

Всё, что передаётся через ajax идёт в кодировке utf8, ваш документ, и скрипт отвечающий на запрос, находится в кодировке utf8?

Comment: У меня на DLE движке, так тег хедер
Но я пробовал лечить тегом 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
Ни чего не помогло? По этому и спрашиваю, странно, но остальная часть, отображается отлично, только вот в этом ДИВе

Comment: Meta - тегом здесь не вылечить, здесь как минимум вот так : header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');, в самом начале.

Comment: Вот пример правильного документа :

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Попробуйте его переделать под себя

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но это начальная школа, Мета не спасает...
Я с этим сталкиваюсь впервые, так как весь сайт отображается на УРА, а именно этот блок нарушается...

Answer (score 0):

```
resource.open('get', link);
```

Замените на

```
resource.open('post', link);
```

Comment: Хм, не думаю, что это как то мне поможет с кодировкой...

Comment: На яве в server.xml здесь:
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

добавить аргумент URIEncoding="UTF-8"
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = 'Ответ от сервера';
iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8//IGNORE', $variable);
```

Это к примеру!

Comment: а без PHP можно? или на ява такое провернуть?